# Jquery ajax POST inconsistent with Hapijs server inject

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, hapi.js

Here is what my Ajax post looks like:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/create",
            data: {
                "question": $('#question').val(),
                "options": options
            },
            success: function() { window.location.href="/view"; }
        });
```

Fairly simple. options is an array of string charachters. The problem is, when I receive on the server end with Hapijs, the request payload shows this object received:

```
{
 question: "..etc..",
 "options[]": [..etc...]
}
```

Why does it add a [] to the options variable name? Normally this wouldn't be a problem for me, but when I do the same thing and simulate a server request in my lab test like this:

```
var test = [..etc..]
// Simulate POST request
var serverOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/create',
    payload: {
        question: 'Question',
        options: test
    }
};
```

It shows that the variable name received is just "options", not "options[]". How can I get jquery to stop adding the [] to the variable name when POSTing? Thanks

Comment: try adding dataType: json to the ajax call

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding datatype: "json" did not help, the variable name received on the server is still options[]. Perhaps this is hapijs doing this and not jquery?

Comment: hmmm not sure....try putting in the array literal into options instead of passing the variable if it's not too long

Comment: try to add `traditional:true` in ajax call